# свои команды для Emmet в Sublime Text 3

Tags: javascript, sublime-text-3, webstorm, emmet

Можно ли как то расширить функциональность Emmet-а
Не заморачиваясь добавить свои команды в Sublime Text 3 ?

Например я хочу чтобы при нажатии клавиши `tab` после введённого слова `log` у меня получалась команда `console.log()`  и так далее

(как в WebStorm, там если ввести `log` и нажать `tab` слово превращается в `console.log()` (или по клавише `enter`, не помню точно))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется сниппеты. Их можно писать какие угодно и сколько угодно почти в любом редакторе. Например для саблайма содержимое для console.log() будет выглядеть так.

```html
<snippet>
 <content><![CDATA[
console.log($0);
]]></content>
 <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
 <tabTrigger>log</tabTrigger>
 <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
 <scope>source.js</scope>
</snippet>
```

К Emmet это никакого отношения не имеет ))

Подробнее почитать можно например вот тут http://rightblog.ru/2702